# How to replace my custom template for product detail page in Magento2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I need to replace my custom template for product detail page in magento2.
I have followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98515/magento2-add-custom-template-to-product-details-page-below-add-to-cart-section) link and updated my code but it is not working.

In my module, I have added catalog_product_view.xml and below code.
Mynamespace\Catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Mynamepace\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Article" name="product.view.art" template="Mynamespace_Catalog::product\view\article.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

This is not working. Can anyone suggest what I am missing here?

My Block Code: 
Mynamepace\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Article.php

```
 <?php 

namespace Mynamespace\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;

class Article extends AbstractProduct 
{


public function showPages()
{

return 'Article';
}

}
```

My phtml - Mynamespace\Catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\article.phtml

```
I am in Article
<?php
```

My Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mynamespace_Catalog" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Please tell me if I have missed something Or at least tell me how to debug this code.

Comment: Have you done cache clearing process and re-indexing  as well as reload static content process if not then do it

Comment: yes sagar, I already cleared cache many times, static deploy done and re-index is done too.. Still same :(

Comment: Are you sure when you fire this command say sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade your custom extension get listed with list of existing magento extension

Comment: if it is possible could you please upload your entire code here that you have done so far

Comment: yes, it is working. xml file is being overridded but not replacing the template.

Comment: I have edited my post. please check if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: what I see is that you are not replacing the template but adding a new block to the existing template

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? jstuardo?

Comment: Have you got any solution to this? If yes then please share. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see a wrong syntax on your layout file Mynamespace\Catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
template="Mynamespace_Catalog::product\view\article.phtml"
```

Change it to:

```
template="Mynamespace_Catalog::product/view/article.phtml"
```

Comment: Nicolas, thanks for identifying, I tried that too, but no luck!

Comment: Any suggestions.. I am stuck guys... need help!